# How to move a branch forward in GIT

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and I would like to know how to move a branch forward.

I have branch named DevInt which we use for developer integration.

I have another feature branch which we will call Feature1.

I've merged the changes in the Feature1 branch into the DevInt branch, however, there have been other changes to DevInt since the Feature1 branch was created.

So now the Feature1 branch is behind and I want to bring it forward so that it is at the same position as DevInt.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your feature branch:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/DevInt
```

Comment: In this example, wouldn't it be:  git rebase origin/DevInt

Comment: or `git pull origin DevInt` depending whether merging or rebasing is your forte.